# How do I draw lines of exact widths in Kivy?

Tags: graphics, kivy

I'm trying to draw some basic graphics here.  Namely, Lines or Rectangles with exact pixel widths.   No fancy anti aliasing or anything else that makes the line appear different.

Can someone give me some instructions or basic code that can achieve this?

I used the basic Line/Rectangle functions and adjusted the width parameter and the color was black.

Here's what solid 2px and 1px lines look like in any graphics program:

[image: desired version]

And here's what it looks like in Kivy:

[image: kivy version]

The Kivy version has a thicker line and a 1 pixel line that is not black. How do i draw pixel perfect lines?

Comment: Note that the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line) does not say that the `width` is pixels. I believe that a 1 pixel wide line that is not pixel aligned gets interpolated among the neighboring pixels. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/A-bityxyoA0)

Comment: Experimentally verified that the line width in pixels is actually twice the specified width. Not sure if that applies to `width=1.0`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that info John.  I think width 1.0 is a special case but value of 1.001 seemed to work for a 2px wide line.   Any idea how to get lines of decimal width like 1.5, 2.5 to show up as solid lines and not blurred at edges?

Answer (score 2):

Due to an ancient design mistake, the `width` property in Kivy actually controls half the line width, as you have observed, with the exception of width 1 in which case the line is drawn using a plain OpenGL instruction and genuinely has width 1 pixel. No, this doesn't make sense.

If you get blurriness after specifying half the width you really need, this is probably because of OpenGL interpolation when the line doesn't actually line up with the display pixels. If you have an example where it seems particularly bad, it might be possible to say more about that.

Comment: As a result of that, a line with width=0.99 is drawn wider than a line with width=1.0